# Downloading and installing the DEBIAN ARM packages and installing them on Termux?

Tags: android-emulator, terminal

Ok, so I was looking for a terminal emulator for android and I found Termux. Then I discovered that it has "apt-get" as a package manager and I played around with it and installed a few packages. Then I had the idea! Debian also runs on a few ARM devices so I should be able to find the URL of the repo where the packages are collected. I searched the internet to  no avail. So now I have two questions: 
- What's the URL to the Kali or Debian package repo containig ARM packages?
- How do I install the packages after downloading "package.deb"?

Comment: Normal Debian packages won't run on Android without modification. Android has its own ABI and some different standard libraries, so executables compiled for GNU/Linux don't run on it.

Comment: Yes but on Termux?

Comment: Termux is just a terminal emulator. It doesn't change what binaries you can run on the system. Termux's own repository contains packages built for Android, which is why they work, but normal packages won't.

Comment: @DanHulme So how do I get started with building a package?

Comment: That's a whole separate question, and the process is different for different projects. Additionally, most projects will need source code changes to be able to build for Android, and we can't teach you all of that here: this isn't a programming site, and it's a very broad topic.

Comment: @DanHulme Can you point me to a guide?

Answer (score 5):

Termux's repository of ARM packages can be found at: [termux.net/dists/stable/main/binary-arm/](https://termux.net/dists/stable/main/binary-arm/)

Additional resources that may be of interest:

- [Termux Help: Package Management](https://termux.com/package-management.html)
- [Termux Help: Termux and Linux](https://termux.com/linux.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have added debian arm / Ubuntu package in termux by editing source.list file

you will find it at

> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/apt/

unfortunately I couldn't sign !

Answer (score 1):

The solution: [HOWTO install Debian 10 (buster) on your non-rooted Android smartphone](https://github.com/sp4rkie/debian-on-termux)

### What is it?

- a shell script to install [Debian 10 (buster)](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/) via [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) in a [Termux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page) environment
- supported Debian versions also include: [Debian testing (bullseye)](https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/), [Debian unstable (sid)](https://www.debian.org/releases/sid/)
- supported architectures include: armel, armhf, arm64, i386, amd64
- no root permissions are required

In other words: exactly what you are looking for.

**Disclaimer**: I am hosting that repository.

Comment: I believe you are hosting that repository as sp4rkie and sparkie seems one and the same. Our site requires disclosure of any affiliation to third-party content, so I went ahead with adding one into the post.

Comment: thanks. I'm not hosting that repos. The repos is hosted on github. I simply wrote some lines of code that (accidentally) provide a solution to the question. I hope I must not justify myself for that.

Comment: Perhaps not "hosting", but it seems you're the owner of the repo, and that still needs to be explicitly mentioned even though it's on a public, non-profit site like GitHub.